# How to respond to request with TcpInboundGateway?

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I would like to develop a TCP Server with Spring Integration but I have a few difficulties...
My server should listen on a port for GPS devices which first identify themselves with their IMEI and needs an Acknowledgment from the server to go further and send the position data to the same TCP server.

I succeeded to get the IMEI but the acknowledgment doesn't reach the device... I'm not even sure if i send it the right way. I read the documentation and other posts and I found out that I had to use `TcpInboundGateway` instead of channel adapter because it's the same session. But do I have to use `TcpOutboundGateway` to send the response back to the device ?

Here is my code :

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class TcpServerConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TcpServerConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    TcpServerProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpServerFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(properties.getPort());
        tcpServerFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());
        return tcpServerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway tcpInGate(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory)  {
        TcpInboundGateway inGateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
        inGateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        inGateway.setRequestChannel(inputChannel());
        inGateway.setReplyChannel(outputChannel());
        return inGateway;
    }

}
```

The message handler class :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MessageHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);

    @Transformer( inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public byte[] consume(byte[] bytes) {
        String message = new String(bytes);
        String byteString = "";
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            byteString += Byte.toString(b) + ", ";
        }
        logger.info("Bytes : " + byteString);
        logger.info("Message : " + message);
        return new byte[]{ 01 };
    }

}
```

Here I always send the Ack (01) to test if it's successfully sent which is not the case.

I added `logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG` and here is what I got :

```
2017-10-02 14:16:44.245  INFO 6340 --- [main] b.thingsplay.Fmb920TcpServerApplication  : Started Fmb920TcpServerApplication in 3.885 seconds (JVM running for 5.38)
2017-10-02 14:16:44.250  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : serverFactory, port=7015 Listening
2017-10-02 14:17:50.161 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Accepted connection from 1.1.1.1
2017-10-02 14:17:50.200 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : New connection ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912
2017-10-02 14:17:50.201 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : serverFactory: Added new connection: ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912
2017-10-02 14:17:50.204 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912 Reading...
2017-10-02 14:17:50.207 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayRawSerializer       : Available to read:17
2017-10-02 14:18:20.576 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[17], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=229435ad-6284-8136-40d4-4fdfe3ef462e, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700575}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.585  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'outputChannel' channel
2017-10-02 14:18:20.587  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.outputChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-10-02 14:18:20.589  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@14c3d44a
2017-10-02 14:18:20.595 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'inputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[17], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=2cc3d793-dc24-705d-1438-d4b3e089d11b, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700594}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.598 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : messageHandler.consume.transformer.handler received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[17], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=2cc3d793-dc24-705d-1438-d4b3e089d11b, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700594}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.608  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] be.thingsplay.tcp.MessageHandler         : Bytes : 0, 15, 51, 53, 50, 48, 57, 52, 48, 56, 51, 50, 54, 54, 52, 55, 53, 
2017-10-02 14:18:20.611  INFO 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] be.thingsplay.tcp.MessageHandler         : Message :  352094083266475
2017-10-02 14:18:20.618 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'outputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=0e5b6c37-ff73-5c46-4c37-0df48d3ba607, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700614}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.620 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.BridgeHandler    : org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler@5b393299 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=0e5b6c37-ff73-5c46-4c37-0df48d3ba607, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700614}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.623 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=0e5b6c37-ff73-5c46-4c37-0df48d3ba607, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700614}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.625 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[17], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a0438a2, ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=2cc3d793-dc24-705d-1438-d4b3e089d11b, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700594}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.628 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912 Message sent GenericMessage [payload=byte[1], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=62138, ip_connectionId=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be:62138:7015:a7151dbf-63c1-4ff5-b158-5707797b8912, ip_localInetAddress=/0.0.0.0, ip_address=1.1.1.1, id=af87b495-fceb-dbdc-c768-a8a81391af75, ip_hostname=ptr-x-x-x-x.dyn.mobistar.be, timestamp=1506946700628}]
2017-10-02 14:18:20.631 DEBUG 6340 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayRawSerializer       : Available to read:0
```

I hope someone will be able to help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `TcpInboundGateway` correct way. Although you might not need `setReplyChannel()` option. In most cases it is fully enough to rely on the `replyChannel` in headers and jsut return from the `@Transformer` method will reach the proper "session" to reply.

I think you use wrong `deserializer`. See `ByteArrayRawSerializer` JavaDocs:

```
 * A byte array (de)serializer that does nothing with the payload; sends it raw.
 * Message termination for assembly purposes is signaled by the client closing the
 * connection. The serializer does not, itself, close the connection after
 * writing the bytes.
 * <p>
 * Because the socket must be closed to indicate message end, this (de)serializer
 * can only be used by uni-directional (non-collaborating) channel adapters, and
 * not by gateways.
```

So, since your client doesn't close the connection for end session, you don't get the reply there. More over this serializer isn't for gateways.

Consider to select the proper (de)serializer with appropriate terminator for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the problem. But what can I use as a serializer when there is no terminating value ? From the doc I have the request looks like this : 'For example IMEI 356307042441013 would be sent as 000f333536333037303432343431303133
First two bytes denote IMEI length. In this case 000F means, that imei is 15 bytes long.'

Comment: I don't know. You have to negotiate with your client to agree the appropriate protocol for messages.